# How to create login on azure ms sql server with access to all databases?

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication

I need to create a login on a server that will have access to all databases on this server.

I have two azure servers: production and stage. I make a copy of a database from prod server on stage server. Then I need to do insert some test data in this new copied database.

The copying process is made on runbooks in azure automation account so every time I want to execute SQL script on a database I need to provide a login&password to a server.

If I create a login TestLogin on stage server and then copy database from prod server to stage, then this login does not have access to a new db. Thus, I need to login as administrator and create a TestUser in this new database for TestLogin.
This does not work for Azure:

```
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO TestLogin;
```

Is there any way I can grant a TestLogin all rights so that it can have access to all the databases on server?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a login in one instance of SQL Server and assign any roles to this user on a specific database, and then copy the database to another SQL Server instance, you have this user in the database, but no login for that user in the second SQL Server. This is also called an "orphaned user". [Here](https://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/sql_orphan_user.htm) is an article that describes how to fix that.

This [does not work on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You have to use [ALTER USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead.

Comment: I get an error:Could not find stored procedure 'sp_change_users_login'.Looks like this stored procedure will not run on azure server

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like I still have to login with admin login and alter user and only then login with new TestLogin.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in comment, you must login with admin, then you have the permission to alter the new user in master DB, set the user as DB manager or db_owner.

If you only create new login or user and don't give it more permission, this login/user only and login the Database but can't access no database.

Fore details, please see [Controlling and granting database access to SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins#additional-server-level-administrative-roles).

Hope this helps.